# .NET MAUI IOS Csvhelper Linking issues

Tags: .net, maui, csvhelper

Background:

.NET 7 MAUI iOS app using Csvhelper nugget to process CSV files.

Problem:

Everything works normally when I choose "Don't Link" in VS2022.
If I choose Link Only Framework SDKs, Csvhelper starts to throw an "Unexpected Error" exception, while displaying contents on the first line of the first CSV correctly. This is an error Csvhelper normally gives if there is an issue with the Csv format, but on this occasion problem only occurs with the code is linked.

Progress so far:

1. I can only assume the linker is trimming a method that is used by the Csvhelper. It is not the Csvhelper itself though as it manages to load the CSV as well as its first line.
2. I cannot debug the solution to find where it fails because it is linked.
3. I've read about preserving Dynamic Dependencies with an annotation. However, I am not sure what to preserve. Is there a recommendation here ? Or on how to figure out which method might be being trimmed ?
4. Digging down into CSVHelper code, exception seems to be generated here:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetRecords<T> ()
{
    if (disposed) {
        throw new ObjectDisposedException ("CsvReader", "GetRecords<T>() returns an IEnumerable<T> that yields records. This means that the method isn't actually called until you try and access the values. e.g. .ToList() Did you create CsvReader inside a using block and are now trying to access the records outside of that using block?");
    }
    if (hasHeaderRecord && headerRecord == null) {
        if (!Read ()) {
            yield break;
        }
        ReadHeader ();
        ValidateHeader<T> ();
    }
    while (Read ()) {
        T val;
        try {
            val = recordManager.Value.Create<T> ();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            CsvHelperException ex2 = (ex as CsvHelperException) ?? new ReaderException (context, "An unexpected error occurred.", ex);
            ReadingExceptionOccurredArgs args = new ReadingExceptionOccurredArgs (ex2);
            if (readingExceptionOccurred?.Invoke (args) ?? true) {
                if (ex is CsvHelperException) {
                    throw;
                }
                throw ex2;
            }
            continue;
        }
        yield return val;
    }
}
```

and `recordManager` is declared as

```
private readonly Lazy<RecordManager> recordManager;
```

I am not sure if this may have anything to do with the `Lazy` declaration, this is a bit on the edge of my .NET knowledge.

Questions:

1. Can this be something other than linker trimming some methods? What other troubleshooting I can do ?
2. If it is likely to be a method being trimmed, is there a way to find this in the build log ? Or by analysing the assembly produced ? A preliminary search through the log didn't help.
3. Would it help if I try to preserve CSVhelper itself, does the preserve logic propagates to the methods called by it ?
4. Any other suggestions you might have.

References:

Preserving code: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/linking?tabs=vs#linker-behavior

Comment: See the Preserve assemblies section of the docs you linked to

Comment: Hi Jason - thanks for your comment. Would this not be equivalent to no trimming at all ? The reason I link the code is because if I don't Appstore Connect complains about many additional permissions (eg, bluetooth, camera) although I don't use any of them. I'll give this a go anyways.

Comment: You can specify which specific assemblies to exclude from linking

Comment: Great, so my question was, how can I identify which assembly to exclude ?

Comment: try each CSVHelper assembly until you find the problem